# What's the correct way of using jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm building something that fades an array of texts in and out.

This is my work so far: http://jsfiddle.net/9j7U6/

I'm fading texts in and out, but the timing is off when I see it rendered.

```
$("#wantPlaceholder").fadeOut().html(wants[i]).fadeIn(2000).delay(3000);
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Comment: Have you read the docs?  Should be pretty clear...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The fades are working so you need to adjust the timing, which you mentioned

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/9j7U6/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a callback. The callback will be called once the animation is done. The following code fades out the element. When it is fully faded out the HTML is modified and then it is faded in again.

```
$("#wantPlaceholder").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).html(wants[i]);
    $(this).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

**Edit:** Well, the looping could be done [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9j7U6/3/):

```
(function myLoop(items, index) {
    index = (items.hasOwnProperty(index) ? index : 0);
    $("#wantPlaceholder").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(this).html(items[index]);
        $(this).fadeIn(1000, function () {
            myLoop(items, index + 1);
        });
    });
}(wants, 0));
```

Comment: +1 for walkthrough with pseudo-code. please make a fiddle with setInterval like the one in the question and it's yours

Answer (score 1):

First the text need to be changed in the fadeOut() handler

```
function rotateWants() {
    var i = 0;
    var wantsLength = wants.length;

    function fade() {
        $("#wantPlaceholder").delay(5000).fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).html(wants[i]);
            i++;
            if (i >= wantsLength) {
                i = 0
            };
        }).fadeIn(2000, fade);
    }

    fade();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nAJE5/)

Comment: Arun, can we speak off-site? isaacmalca1*at*gmail, send me a line pls.